# How to display specific forms in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I need to display the system login form and the system registration form on the same page but different panels (not tabbed like the default). I don't want to build a form from scratch using the forms api. I want to pull the accrual forms from the system and use them. The result should be much like the home page of facebook before you login, on the same page you can either login or sign up. I want to do all this from code, not from a module but from the page.tpl.php file. I have a special function that will display a completely different page for the home page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using blocks with conditional views instead of hard coding this into your template file, but if that's really what you want to do, you basically just need to use [drupal_render](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_render/7) and [drupal_get_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) in the appropriate places in your template file i.e.:

```
Login:
<?php print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login')); ?>
 - OR -
Register:
<?php print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_register_form')); ?>
```